# Where can I find Linux-compatible apps?

Tags: drivers

Just swapped to ubuntu from Windows 11, and seem to have trouble installing apps that were previously accessible. For example, the xbox application file will download, but the Archive Manager cannot open it. Is there a way around this? Perhaps a drive you have to download post-setup?

Comment: What is an "xbox application file?" Where did you get it from? What leads you to believe that a Windows application is compatible with Linux? (They generally are not compatible.) Please keep in mind that we cannot see your screen, so help us to help you.

Comment: @user535733 Just trying to install the xbox app off of their site. Is their an alternate option for it? I have a game pass I'm trying to reconnect

Comment: Which XBox app? Who is "they" in "their site"?

Answer (score 3):

Any windows related file will not work on Linux There is WINE and that is sort of a compatibility layer but it is a hit and often miss type of software that requires a lot of tinkering and knowledge about how WINE works. Games that require validation for instance mostly do not work with Linux as the validation does not pass their security checks and when it does an update tends to kill it rather sooner than later.

"Steam" is the piece of tool for gaming on Linux. But that app is not going to be on Steam.

If you want a more true Windows experience install virtualbox or vmware player, install windows in it and install the xbox app in that. The only thing is that your performance (GPU and CPU) takes a bit of a hit (you run an OS, a software and a 2nd OS) so you need a moderate to very good bit of hardware.